# Utilize script in Raspberry Pi JS

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, raspberry-pi

I want my Raspberry pi to be able to access some endpoints.  The information appears to be on this page:

[here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_js)

However, I can't figure out how to get Pi JS to recognize gapi.  I think I'm doing something wrong because I can't just copy/paste this script:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init">
</script>
```

So that I can run the following:

```
var ROOT = 'https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api';
gapi.client.load('your_api_name', 'v1', function() {
  doSomethingAfterLoading();
}, ROOT);
```

Anyone know how I can get PIJS to access the endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

PI JS isn't HTML and isn't the kind of Javascript environment you would get in a browser, where you have access to things like a DOM for the current HTML document. The Google Javascript Client Library is intended to be used in web applications. PI JS is a Javascript runtime for embedded applications.

Even if you could include the code it relies on a browser OAuth flow which would not work in this type of application. What you are looking for is the Google OAuth 2.0 flow for devices (see the section on Calling a Google API):

**Using OAuth 2.0 for Devices**
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices